# JS: Get IDs of objects in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I need to get all IDs of a set of objects in the correct hierarchical order.

*Update:* In this example the IDs are in alphabetical order, but they should represent random strings.

```
[
  { _id: 'abc', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'def', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'ghi', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 3, type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'jkl', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'mno', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'pqr', parent: 'mno', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'stu', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 4, type: 'item' }
]
```

Let me give a short explanation for my data structure:
There are several items (`type`). In the first level all items/group have the parent `mainID`.

So the for the first level elements the IDs are: `['abc','def','ghi','stu']`.
The third element (`ghi`) is a *group* element which has two more subelements - which have the parent `ghi`.

The second subelement ('mno') is also a group, which has one subelement.

*The objects in the initial array can have a shuffled order, which makes the problem for me.*
The order of elements in each level is determined by the order value (ascending).

So the initial array could also look like:

```
[
  { _id: 'ghi', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 3, type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'jkl', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'mno', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'group' },
  { _id: 'pqr', parent: 'mno', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'stu', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 4, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'abc', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' },
  { _id: 'def', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'item' }
]
```

In a better visual way the objects represent this structure:

```
abc
def
ghi
  jkl
  mno
    pqr
stu
```

*What I need is the IDs in the order from top to bottom*

So the result should be:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu']
```

My attempt doesn't work because of the nested structure:

```
(elements) => {
  const result = []
  elements
    .filter(item => (item.parent === item.main))
    .forEach(elm => {
      result.push(elm._id)
      if (elm.type === 'group') {
        getOrderedId(elements, elm._id)
      }
    })
  return result
}
```

Comment: Can you sort on `order` primarily then on the alphabetical `id` secondarily? If so you could write a custom sort method that uses `order`, and in the case they are similar, uses `id`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @lemieuxster The IDs are random strings (updated my post with this info - sorry for missing that)

Comment: What is the correct criteria,               parent = mainID, order asc,   if any element has childs ... then print all_subchild with same_parent, order asc...after that the rest of mainID, order, .... and the result are _id alone array

Comment: It's very confusing the way you asked this and presented the data. Visually, I understand what you are saying, but then your array (re)presentation is not correct. Can you update the code with actual (segment) of nested structure? If they are all at the same level, it shouldn't be able to sort them - it doesn't matter if they are random strings.

Comment: @Sk. For each level the order value and if there is a group element we have to go to the next level which is also ordered by the order value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a Map, keyed by `_id` values, where each entry starts with an empty array, that needs to be populated with the children of that parent (if it has children). An extra key is added to represent the `main` entry, i.e. the root.

Then just iterate the input to inject each object in the appropriate array of the above tree structure.

Then finally perform an in-order traversal (using recursion) in that tree structure and yield the objects as they are visited.

The following code assumes that:

- All objects belong to the same tree (have the same `main` property).
- The `order` values don't leave gaps and start with 1.

The `type` property is not used -- it is redundant information.

```js
function ordered(elements) {
    if (!elements.length) return [];
    const rootId = elements[0].main;
    const children = new Map(elements.map(e => [e._id, []])).set(rootId, []);
    elements.forEach(e => children.get(e.parent)[e.order-1] = e);
    return [...(function * visit(id) {
        if (!children.has(id)) return;
        for (let child of children.get(id)) {
            yield child;
            yield * visit(child._id);
        }
    })(rootId)];
}

const elements = [{ _id: 'ghi', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 3, type: 'group' }, { _id: 'jkl', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' }, { _id: 'mno', parent: 'ghi', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'group' }, { _id: 'pqr', parent: 'mno', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' }, { _id: 'stu', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 4, type: 'item' }, { _id: 'abc', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 1, type: 'item' }, { _id: 'def', parent: 'mainID', main: 'mainID', order: 2, type: 'item' }];

console.log(ordered(elements));
```

Comment: Indeed, that is what I assumed. Or did you see something that violates that rule?

Comment: How do I rewrite `forEach(e => children.get(e.parent)[e.order-1] = e)`? Because it doesn't match standardJS with `arrow function should not return assignment`

Comment: You can make it a statement block: `forEach(e => { children.get(e.parent)[e.order-1] = e } )`

Comment: Last question: Would it make a difference if order value start with `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: Yes, it would. In that case change `e.order-1` by just `e.order`.